# Distance between two vectors: Vector Calculus

Tags: vector-analysis

I have a parametric equation

x= 24 sin (2πt)
y= -24 cos(2πt)+35

This parametric equation is related to a diagram of a Ferris wheel, and is the equation of motion of a point A on the diagram which is attached. [Ferris Wheel Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmbsQ.png)

I need to find the cartesian equation of the path of A, since the original equation given on the diagram is a parametric equation and find the distance between O and A when t=0.25.

I have found the cartesian equation and it is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI2CI.png), but I don't know how to find the distance between O and A on the diagram (A is one of the smaller double Ferris wheel). Do I assume that since O is stationary it is on the origin of the plane, and I just work out how far away from the origin is A at t=0.25, or am I just approaching this wrong? It has been a long time since I have done vectors, so I am sorry if I sound completely wrong. Has the distance formula got anything to do with it?

Then next I have to state the position vector of point B at time t minutes. I have no idea how to approach this, so this will be of additional help.

Correct me if I am wrong in my thinking somewhere.

Thanks

Comment: Do the two wheels have the same radii, and are they the same distance from the point where the center of the balance arm?

Comment: Yes the wheels have the same radii (exactly the same wheel) and are the same distance from the centre of the balance arm

Comment: @coffeemath I hope you understand

Comment: Instead of posting an [expanded version of your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2723417/265466), you should edit this one to include the additional information.