# Distance between two vectors or two points: vector calculus

Tags: vector-analysis

I have the following parametric equation:

$x = 24 \sin (2πt), y = -24 \cos(2πt) + 35$

This parametric equation is related to a diagram of a Ferris wheel, and is the equation of motion of a point $A$ on the diagram which is attached. [Ferris Wheel Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuNji.png)

I need to find the cartesian equation of the path of $A$, since the original equation given on the diagram is a parametric equation and find the distance between $O$ and $A$ when $t=0.25$.

I have found the cartesian equation and it is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj7eB.png), but I don't know how to find the distance between $O$ and $A$ on the diagram ($A$ is one of the smaller double Ferris wheel). Do I assume that since $O$ is stationary it is on the origin of the plane, and I just work out how far away from the origin is $A$ at $t=0.25$, or am I just approaching this wrong? It has been a long time since I have done vectors, so I am sorry if I sound completely wrong. Has the distance formula got anything to do with it?

Then next I have to state the position vector of point B at time $t$ minutes. I have no idea how to approach this, so this will be of additional help.

Correct me if I am wrong in my thinking somewhere.

Extra information: The radii of $A$ and $B$ are the same and the distance between $AX$ and $BX$ is the same so they are equidistant.

Comment: Based on the given parametric equation, this problem has already assumed that the point $O$ is the origin. As far as the motion of $B$ goes, you need to know its distance from $X$. I suppose that you can assume the rotating arm is symmetric about $X$. The equation of motion will be similar to that of $A$.

Comment: This is a slightly expanded version of [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2723343/265466). You should edit that question to include any additional information instead of posting a new one.

Comment: I would recommend (to moderators) that the previous question be marked a duplicate of this one, since this one has the extra info about the other circle. [I don't know if that's done here...]